# Solution to optimize code that exceeds limits of 50k rows returned

Tags: apex, governorlimits, custom-controller

I would need guidance over how to avoid getting de 50k limit rows on one visualforce page that monitors the transactions that are going to be made on the present day + 2 next days, shows a lot of information related to both the transaction and the client, and if the transaction appears suspicious (doesn't fit at all the client's usual movements) its checked, to do this we need to get all other transactions from all the clients involved in transactions that are going to be made on today,tomorrow and the next one. So thats like, A LOT.

The actual version of the code which started working but since it didn't follow scalability best practices and now isn't working because of too many rows returned (the code was based on a lot of AggregateResults), one for each column needed with very selective queries. (I don't paste code since it's like 550 lines or so).

This is highly inneficient and i was wondering what's the best way to do it without ever getting again error because of row limitation?

The only ideas I came up with are these:

*Execute a Batch that calculates the table and then the visualforce page only has to load this calculations that would be stored in a custom object.

*Use only 1 query to return every Transaction that we need to do calculations related to the clients that are performing Transactions on next 2 days+today. (But eventually with this solution you will reach still the 50k problem).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what's the logic on your page, but you might want to check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm for read-only mode which has a limit of 1kk records.

Comment: If you are just reading the data, you may use @ReadOnly annotation in ur apex controller

Comment: @olesmalkov we were probably typing at the same time :)

Comment: This sounds amazing, the problem is that the page also features modifications like blocking transactions and adding comments to the transactions. So there are also modifications made on the page. :( 

I'm sorry i didn't provided much info but it's pretty chaotic to paste 550 lines of inefficient code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us much to work with, but there are two basic strategies you can apply:

1. Add `WHERE` clauses (joined with `AND`) until your collection is small enough.
2. Add `LIMIT 50000`.

The second option is the only way you can *guarantee* you won't go over the limit. Although depending on your context, you may have already used up your query rows. To determine the *remaining* query row limit:

```
Integer remainingRows = Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows();
```

Additionally, as noted in the comments, `@ReadOnly` [annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm) will give you higher limits. You can set it for the [whole page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm) as follows:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" readOnly="true">
```

> Normally, queries for a single Visualforce page request may not retrieve more than 50,000 rows. In read-only mode, this limit is relaxed to allow querying up to 1 million rows.

Comment: The actual version has really selective queries that can't be improved. Every query has like 7 filters with 'AND'.
The LIMIT 50k isn't good neither since this has monitor EVERYTHING. On this tool depends a security audit we will get on some months so we have to prove that this app tracks every transaction that goes through the system showed to our compliance officer.  
If for example one suspicious transactions isn't showed up there and we don't block and at the end it's some illegal transaction with bad intentions (money laundering,etc) we can have a lot of problems.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn Check out `readonly` mode as outlined above.

Comment: So, since my controller also makes Updates on some objects, the solution maybe would be do a ReadOnly visualforce page that schedules the modifications with a really low offset?
Does this make sense?

Comment: You can't schedule anything in `readonly` mode. You might be able to use `@RemoteActions` since they change context...or be creative with linking to a page that has write access.

Comment: This is it. I can solve it combining Remote Actions and readonly mode. 

Also I didn't knew about remoteActions and they seem a powerful way to bypass some limitations like this and add some powerful logic to visualforce pages.

Really appreciated Adrian.